# How can I force two elements to always stay on the same line in a <td>

Tags: html, css

The code is pretty simple:

```
<table id="tabel_user" style="width: 100%; border: 0; background-color: white;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="border: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px;">
        <label for="abcd"><input class="check_useri" id="abcd" name="abcd" type="checkbox" /> abcd </label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

They stay neatly on the same line unless the text in the label gets really long and the table needs to stretch to accomodate it, then the text sometimes gets forced below the checkbox. How can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can force inline elements to stay on the same line using the CSS property [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop):

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
  this content will not be wrapped
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works fine, and is responsive:

```
table {
width:100%;
display: inline-block;
}
td, th {
max-width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a `white-space` may be one of the way to get it done, but as a tabular data, its better if you fix the max size of width of the label instead

```
label { width: 100px; display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: `<tr valign="top">`
This will make the vertical align at the top.

Comment: In 2013 you're giving solution that was depracated (in favor of CSS styles) years ago?

Comment: The questioner asked about tables, why are you blaming the answerer for not using CSS? Tables and table element attributes to this day still do things that are a pain to pull off with CSS

Comment: @Amalgovinus `valign` is not supported in HTML5, so it doesn't even work.

Comment: It's deprecated, but to my knowledge support has not been dropped--and attributes like these are still essential for things like HTML emails, in which positioning CSS is rarely available. There's an equivalent vertical-align CSS prop they can use instead if needed. CSS3 has not completely replaced oldschool tables.