# How to force element to stay on the same line as last word previous element?

Tags: html, css

This is similar to [How can I force two elements to always stay on the same line in a <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008395/how-can-i-force-two-elements-to-always-stay-on-the-same-line-in-a-td), but I would like the element only to line up with the -last word- of the previous element.

### Example

```
<th>
  {dynamic text}
  <i>{static icon}</i>
</th>
```

Given sufficient room, we would get:

```
dynamic text here{icon}
```

If there isn't enough room, it would wrap:

```
dynamic text
here{icon}
```

But it should never put the {icon} on it's own line like this:

```
some text
here
{icon}
```

I would like the static icon to stick to the last word of the dynamic text.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `nowrap`. Here are the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). `nowrap` let's you keep several words on a single line without braking.

Take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/QboBpK?editors=110).

CSS:

```
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
Some <span class="nowrap">text with</span> extra text.
```

Comment: I had been messing around trying to get nowrap to work for my needs. In your example, "text with" stays on one line. What I would be looking for is making "extra text" stay on the same line as "with" (when these are separate elements).

Comment: Why don't you use **<span class="nowrap">with extra text</span>**? I don't really see the problem to be honest...

Comment: They are different elements. I have "text text text <i element>" and would like the <i element> to stick to the last word of text, but not to the others. What's more, these fields are dynamic, so I can't do "text text <span class="no wrap">text <i></span>", because I don't know how much text there will be. I think I may need to parse this out with javascript before displaying it, then use nowrap.

Comment: Can you please update your question with your actual html and add some realistic use cases please? This is really confusing..

Answer (score -1):

I think set display: inline is better, consider it's asking stick to last word instead of whole line, and it's wrappable.

Comment: Down voting because this doesn't answer the question. The items are already displayed inline by default. The question is how to stick the icon to the last word so it doesn't end up orphaned. Having text that says "taxable income" with a tooltip that falls off to the next line doesn't look good or make sense. That's what the question is about fixing.